# How do I include the same Web Component dependency in multiple Components without "duplicate registry" error

Tags: web-component, rollupjs, es6-module-loader, umd

I am making a lib similar to Polymer Material. I have individual files I use rollup to create a single ESM, CJS, and UMD file. The ESM file is the main in the package.json. I have a situation like this

```
Header
  Icon-Button
Icon-Button
```

The icon button Uses Mustache so I need to include it using the `rollup-plugin-node-resolve`. I then import the library in Header and create a UMD file that is imported into my we app like this...

```
// Pug
script(src="/ui-components/header/dist/index.umd.js")
script(src="/ui-components/icon-button/dist/index.umd.js")

// Express
// @me/icon-button
// @me/header
const uiPath = path.join(__dirname, './node_modules/@me');
app.use('/ui-components', express.static(uiPath));
```

I get the following in the browser console on load...

> Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "me-icon-button" has already been used with this registry

How do libraries handle this? I thought about removing the resolve plugin for mustache and assuming it is included globally. However, it seems pretty onerous to make everyone find a way to import mustache into window and not something most libraries do. I could also do something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54211849/uncaught-domexception-failed-to-execute-define-on-customelementregistry-th) suggests...

```
customElements.get("me-icon-button")||customElements.define("me-icon-button", IconButton, {...});
```

But having that multiple times in my code does not seem right either.

So How do I include multiple web components that reference other similar components?

Comment: with JS module import

Comment: Can you expand? Even if I run as ESM modules (which I am not sure fully works given the dep support) this still gets ran 2x. So for example if I load the ESM version of Header it says it can't load the icon-button without using something like a global (says it needs to start with / or ./ etc). Also this is UMD which does not use type=module. So I am a bit confused as to how this sentence helps.